# @ngrx Effect does not run the second time

Tags: effects, ngrx

I've just started learning about @ngrx/store and @ngrx.effects and have created my first effect in my Angular/Ionic app. It runs ok the first time but if I dispatch the event to the store again (i.e when clicking the button again), nothing happens (no network call is made, nothing in console logs). Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong?  Here's the effect:

```
@Effect() event_response$ = this.action$
    .ofType(SEND_EVENT_RESPONSE_ACTION)
    .map(toPayload)
    .switchMap((payload) => this.myService.eventResponse(payload.eventId,payload.response))
    .map(data => new SentEventResponseAction(data))
    .catch((error) => Observable.of(new ErrorOccurredAction(error)));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It sounds like an error is occurring. In that situation, the action in the observable returned by `catch` will be emitted into the effect's stream and the effect will then complete - which will prevent the effect from running after the error action is emitted.

Move the `map` and the `catch` into the `switchMap`:

```ts
@Effect() event_response$ = this.action$
  .ofType(SEND_EVENT_RESPONSE_ACTION)
  .map(toPayload)
  .switchMap((payload) => this.myService
    .eventResponse(payload.eventId, payload.response)
    .map(data => new SentEventResponseAction(data))
    .catch((error) => Observable.of(new ErrorOccurredAction(error)))
);
```

Composing the `catch` within the `switchMap` will prevent the effect from completing if an error occurs.

Comment: Does this mean using Angular's global error handler won't work with effects? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47896171/is-it-possible-to-throw-errors-inside-ngrx-effects-without-completing-the-observ

Comment: This is still true with `pipe`able operators and `catchError`. Took me a while to find this question! Thank you.

Comment: For reference - you can do this without entering callback hell and just add a catchError at the end of the pipe: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/646#issuecomment-398640097

Comment: @Adam Nice. However, I'd suggest returning `caught.pipe(startWith(/* error action */))` instead of explicitly dispatching via the store - as done in the linked GitHub comment - which is not something I think should be done in an effect.

Comment: @cartant - That's getting back into pipe's inside pipe's. Can you do: `.pipe(...,catchError((err,caught) => caught),startWith(() => /* error action */)`? I find it gross to do store.dispatch in an effect too, I just find it less gross than putting pipes inside pipes.

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood you, that will always start with your error action. IMO, explicitly dispatching via the store is a far greater sin. Effects are an abstraction over the store.

Answer (score 5):

You must move `map()` and `catchError()` into `swithchMap()` as following

```
@Effect()
public event_response$ = this.action$.pipe(
    ofType(SEND_EVENT_RESPONSE_ACTION),
    switchMap((payload) => {
        return this.myService.eventResponse(payload.eventId,payload.response).pipe(
            map((data: DataType) => new SentEventResponseAction(data)),
            catchError((error) => Observable.of(new ErrorOccurredAction(error)))
        })
    );
 );
```

Please note that, `evetResponse()` method inside `myService` should return an observable in order to use pipe afterward.
In case your method inside service returns `Promise`, you can convert it into an observable by the use of `from` in the rxjs package as below:

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';
...
const promise = this.myService.eventResponse(payload.eventId,payload.response);
const observable = from(promise);
return observable.pipe(...
```

For more and detail description take a look at this [link](https://medium.com/city-pantry/handling-errors-in-ngrx-effects-a95d918490d9)