# ngrx - Weird Behavior on Effects

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

As stated in the title, I'm facing an issue where all of my effects work properly only in these cases:

- I'm already logged in
- I'm not logged in

If I manage to logout and login with another user the problem occurs. Only each `ngOnInit`doing the action dispatch gets called. No effects get fired.

I have two modules, **app.module** and **pages.module**. The first one declares only components for not logged in users such as, login/register/reset. The second ones declares only components for the logged in user.

In **app.module.ts** I import all the reducers and set them up like `StoreModule.provideStore(reducer)`. In **pages.module.ts**, another module, I import and activate the effects like `EffectsModule.run(TestEffects)`.

With the following code only the log inside `ngOnInit` gets called.  A log inside the effect never gets called.

**test.component.ts**:

```
/** ngrx **/
import * as reducers from '../../reducers';
import * as testActions from './actions/test.actions';

. . .

constructor(private _store: Store<reducers.State>){
    this._store.select(reducers.getStuff)
        .subscribe(stuff => console.log(stuff));
}

ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Dispatching Load Action');
    this._store.dispatch(new testActions.LoadAction());
}
```

**test.actions.ts**:

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';

export const ActionTypes = {
    LOAD: type('[Test] Load'),
    LOAD_SUCCESS: type('[Test] Load Success'),
};

export class LoadAction implements Action {
    type = ActionTypes.LOAD;
    constructor() {}
}

export class LoadActionSuccess implements Action {
    type = ActionTypes.LOAD_SUCCESS;
    constructor(public payload: SomeType) {}
}

export type Actions
  = LoadAction
  | LoadActionSuccess
```

**test.effects.ts**:

```
@Injectable()
export class TestEffects {
  @Effect() load$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(testActions.ActionTypes.LOAD)
    .map(toPayload)
    .switchMap(() => this._testService.getStuff()
      .map(result => new testActions.LoadActionSuccess(result))
      .catch((error) => Observable.of({type: error}))
    )
  ;

  constructor(private _testService: TestService, private actions$: Actions) {}
}
```

**test.reducer.ts**:

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
/** ngrx **/
import * as sidebarActions from '../actions/test.actions';

export interface State {
    stuff: SomeType
};

export const initialState: State = {
    stuff: new SomeType()
};

export function testReducer(state = initialState, action: Action): State {
    switch (action.type) {
        case testActions.ActionTypes.LOAD_SUCCESS:
            return {
                stuff: new SomeType(action.payload)
            }
        default: {
            return state;
        }
    }
}

export const getStuff = (state: State) => state.stuff;
```

In my **package.json** I have:

```
{
    "dependencies" : {
        "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
        . . .,
        "@ngrx/core": "^1.2.0",
        "@ngrx/effects": "^2.0.4",
        "@ngrx/store": "^2.2.3",
        . . .
    },
    "devDependencies" : {
        . . .
        "ngrx-store-freeze": "^0.1.9",
        . . .
    }
}
```

I don't really understand this behavior. I also took a loot on ngrx github issues and related questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44180361/ngrx-effect-does-not-run-the-second-time) but I'm not really able to solve this.

> I'm guessing it may be caused by the fact that I have these two
>   different modules

**EDIT**:

Moving the effects and their services inside **app.module** leads to the same behavior.

**What Am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Not a solution to your problem, but have you considered updating ngrx/store to version 4?

Comment: Hi @Daniel B, yes but I have some problems bound to angular version. Will update it when angular 5 comes out.

Comment: Okay, I'll see if I can reproduce your problem!

Comment: I tried reproducing with all the information you gave us, but no matter what I did, the effect always ran without the effect-observable completing (so dispatching the load-action multiple times in a row worked). I tried it with the service succeeding and failing/throwing, importing pages.module before/after ´provideStore()´ as well as moving around service and effect between modules. Shot in the dark: is `pages.module` loaded eagerly or lazily? If it is lazy, try loading eagerly and look if this is the culprit. Hope you can figure it out, good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your comment @mtx. You sure deserve some credits for such an effort. I'll let you know tomorrow. Anyways I'm planning to update ngrx etc as angular 5 comes out. I'm really starting to suspect that ngrx version is causing it, too bad I had to go out in production with this oldie one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It came out the problem was caused by an old version of **ngrx**. I managed to upgraded everything to version **4.1.1** following the [migration guide](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/MIGRATION.md) and the different instructions in READMEs.