# Why action doesn't trigger Effect the second time it runs?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, ngrx, ngrx-effects

> Effect:

```
@Effect()
  loadDocsEffect$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(myActionTypes.LoadDocs),
    mergeMap(action => this.myService.getDocs()),
    map(data => new LoadDocsSuccess(data)),
    catchError(error => Observable.of(new LoadDocsFailure(error)))
  );
```

It works when I have data returned, but when the server responds with an error - 404 for example, the observable is complete and doesn't trigger the effect the second time I dispatch an action. I looked for a way to handle the error properly and to continue the observable stream so I could subscribe to it in my component and act accordingly.

The solution in [@ngrx Effect does not run the second time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44180361/ngrx-effect-does-not-run-the-second-time) did not work for me, or I couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to `catchError` on request instead of the `actions$`. To do this, you will need to modify your code as following:

```
mergeMap(action => 
  this.myService.getDocs().pipe(
    map(data => new LoadDocsSuccess(data)),
    catchError(error => Observable.of(new LoadDocsFailure(error)))
  )
)
```

Answer (score 3):

I guarantee you that this is the right way to do it. How do I know? There is a long talk about this exact issue on the ngrx Udemy course and this is the solution they provide. Note that is is essential to use `catchError` else an HTTP error response (any non 2xx response) will disable this effect.

```
@Effect()
  loadDocsEffect$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(myActionTypes.LoadDocs),
    mergeMap((action) => {
      // essential to catchError else an HTTP error response will disable this effect
      return this.myService.getDocs().pipe(
        map(data => new LoadDocsSuccess(data)),
        catchError((err) => {
          return of(null)
        })
      )
    }),
    tap(res => console.log(res)) // you won't want this line but useful for debugging
  );
```

In this example, if the HTTP request succeeds the result of `new LoadDocsSuccess(data)` will be logged inside tap. If the HTTP request fails, `null` will be logged inside tap. Of course, you may want to provide some different catchError logic but you get the idea.