# redux-observable can't catch error from emitted action, error stops action stream

Tags: redux, rxjs, redux-observable

If a js error occurs as the result of an emitted action from a redux-observable epic then it stops all epics from listening to new actions. This is pretty nasty since on the front-end it still appears as if the app is working but in the background nothing is getting saved.

I tried catching the error in my epic but for some reason it doesn't catch errors that are caused by the resulting emitted action (see example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/redux-observable-playground-qtughj?file=ping-pong.js)

I thought that upgrading to version 1.0.0 redux-observable could fix the issue but unfortunately it remains.

Is there any way that errors caused by a redux-observable emitted action can be caught?

The issue is different than [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52683711/why-action-doesnt-trigger-effect-the-second-time-it-runs) since the error is getting triggered in a reducer that occurs after the epic has emitted it's output redux action so catching it with `.error` in the chain of observables doesn't work (see [example above](https://stackblitz.com/edit/redux-observable-playground-qtughj?file=ping-pong.js) for a demo).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After discussing this issue in the [redux-observable Github repo](https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable/issues/591) the safest solution seems to be to create some custom Redux middleware to stop the error from bubbling all the way back up to the root epic e.g.

```
const store = createStore(rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(epicMiddleware, store => next => action => {
    try {
      next(action);
    } catch (e) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        throw e;
      });
    }
  })
);
```